# W3wp hih cpu usage and non-existent web pages

Tags: cpu-usage, w3wp

When I try to display a non-existent page on our web site the w3wp.exe process uses 13% cpu and stays at that level. For each additional non-existent page request an additional 13% of the cpu is used. Of course, after several requests the total cpu usage is up to 95-100% and the site becomes unusable.

I kill off the w3wp.exe process and everything goes back to normal. After awhile several random users go to non-existent pages and the cpu goes up to 100% again.

Researching the problem I stumbled across the idea that the web.config httperrors section was locked and potentially causing problems. I and my hosting firm technical staff tried the suggestions in this post: http://forums.iis.net/p/1159721/1912266.aspx. None of these suggestions solved the problem.

I looked at Worker Processe in IIS and that told me nothing.

I looked at Failed Request Tracing and that did not help either.

Obviously, I'm looking for any other suggestions on how to diagnosis and solve this problem.

Thanks,

Ed

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.iis.net/timamm/archive/2012/02/11/asp-net-and-iis-performance-troubleshooting-tools-3-key-resources.aspx). I've actually used `Jose Reyes’ ASP.NET Perfecto tool` to work out that a Page_Init on X page was being slow due to X. You can only really use this tool though, if you can get remote desktop access to the server - as you need to setup performance counters.

FREB / Failed Request Tracing (FRT) should also be able to tell you where it's all hanging, although I didn't find it as useful as the above. (Seems you also agree :p).

Also, may sound weird, but if it's a non existant page, I guess these are being handled using Custom Errors / Error Pages? So surely the page can't be that intensive! In any case, FREB/FRT should be able to you if that IS the case.

There's also the `PerfView Tool`, which I haven't personally used, but is apparently quite nifty.

HTH

Comment: Ian, FRT shows W3wp calling AspNetMapHandleEnter but never leaving when I surf to a non-existent page. Someone suggested getting the SubStatus code but I could not find one in the FRT logs.

Comment: So you never see a `AspNetMapHandlerLeave` ? That's not that useful really anyway - the part that is useful is what module it's hanging on. If you just expand all on the `Complete Request Trace`, you should be able to find your hanging handler and see what module it's hanging on. Then you can start properly debugging :-)